# Android SQlite: Querying table rows by date range from today backwards?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I get a date from the server in "MM/dd/yyy" form, then I convert it into milliseconds using the following function:

```
public static long getSimpleDateToMillis(String simpleDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date date = formatter.parse(simpleDate);
        return date.getTime();
}
```

Then afterwards I save the result into the database as int.

Right now I'm stucked in what seems like a dead-end for me. I can't find a way through searching and from my stock knowledge on how I would be able to filter my cursorloader by project_date column which is saved as integer in the database.

In what way would I be able to query such that it would:
Select all row from projects table where the project_date is today and backwards (yesterday and so on).

I tried this one but seems to be really not the answer.

```
String [] projection = new String []{};
        String selection = "datetime("+ ProjectsEntry.COLUMN_PROJECT_DATE + "/1000, 'unixepoch') =? ";
        String [] selectionArgs = new String[]{" date('now')"};
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                JobsContract.JobsEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null);
```

I haven't found any other reference that would point me, so I'm hoping someone might also have encountered this perhaps.

Comment: "datetime("+ ProjectsEntry.COLUMN_PROJECT_DATE + "/1000, 'unixepoch') ``<``=?  - have you tried "less-than-or-equal"??

Comment: @Grisgram won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do something quite similar, but using full timesteamp i.e. long rather than int.

First I have this method to get the TimeStamp, to get today's date/time as of midnight (bar 1 millisecond):-

```
/**
 *
 * @return  1 millsecond before midnight today
 */
private long getDateTimeOfAllofToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); // tomorrow
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,-1);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Then I create the respective where clause e.g. :-

```
filter = DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ACTON_COL +
        " <= " +
        Long.toString(getDateTimeOfAllofToday());
```

This is used via a rawQuery so not exactly what you want but easy enough to to change `" <= "` to `" <=?"` and then use
 `String [] selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(getDateTimeOfAllofToday())};` or a modified version to get integer.